# Why is BuildConfig.DEBUG set to false when executing local unit tests via Gradle?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Context:

One of my local unit tests makes a call to a method that I am testing which has logic that relies on whether "BuildConfig.DEBUG" is true or false.

Question:

I noticed that when I run my unit tests **inside** Android Studio using the green play button BuildConfig.DEBUG is "true" as expected. This is probably because I set the build variant to debug.

However when I run the same test via terminal using a command such as "./gradle test" it is set to false.

Is this expected behaviour and why?

Comment: Post your app `build.gradle` file

Comment: @flopshot Unfortunately I can't post it, but the only thing I can think of that can be related in the build.gradle is how I am defining the sourceSets for main, androidTest, and debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have two flavors, `debug` and `release`.
If you run `./gradlew test`, it will run two test task which are `testDebugUnitTest` and `testReleaseUnitTest`.

There are simple test case like following.

```
@Test fun test() {
    assertTrue(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
}
```

It will succeed in the `testDebugUnitTest` task and fail in the `testReleaseUnitTest` task.
Also `test` task will fail.
Because `test` task dependsOn `testReleaseUnitTest`.